# How to change property of QML item from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing a small QT(5.12) application in C++, which will be moving center of QMap every second. I am trying to update the coordinates so the center will refresh, but after debugging it, it's always staying the same (original value). That's my first attempt with QML, so I am helping myself with the link bellow, but apparently I am not doing something right.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Update function called every second by timer

```
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

void MainWindow::UpdateCoordinates()
{
    float LATDEGM = (60 * 1853.181);
    float DEG2RAD = (PI / 180.0);

    QString speedData = ui->sboxSpeed->text();
    bool ok;
    AirSpeed = speedData.toInt(&ok);
    AirCourse = (AirCourse + 360) % 360;

    Dx = AirSpeed * sin((float)AirCourse * DEG2RAD);
    Dy = AirSpeed * cos((float)AirCourse * DEG2RAD);

    QString dat = ui->txtLatitude->text();
    Lat = dat.toDouble();
    QString dat2 = ui->txtLongtitude->text();
    Lon = dat2.toDouble();

    Dx /= 3.6;
    Dy /= 3.6;

    Lat += Dy / LATDEGM;
    Lon += Dx / (LATDEGM * cos(Lat * DEG2RAD));

    ui->txtLatitude->setText(QString::number(Lat));
    ui->txtLongtitude->setText(QString::number(Lon));

    // Using QQmlComponent
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Map.qml")));
    QObject *object = component.create();
    QObject *map = object->children().at(1);

    if (map)
    {
        map->setProperty("newLatitude", Lat);
        map->setProperty("newLongitude", Lon);
        std::cout << "Property value:" << map->property("latitude").toDouble() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Property value:" << map->property("longitude").toDouble() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Map.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item{
    id: itemControl
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    property alias newLongitude : map.longitude;
    property alias newLatitude : map.latitude;

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri"
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        maximumZoomLevel: 15
        minimumZoomLevel: 15
        width: 512
        height: 512
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center {
            property real latitude: 45.5082047
            property real longitude: 13.5757492
        }
        zoomLevel: 14
    }
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve], Where is the QQuickView?

Comment: You are creating an object on every update call, you should find the existing object and update that. And furthermore, you are assigning 'newLatitude' but then log 'latitude' (last lines of update call), which seems counter-intuitive

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the comment. I am using QQmlComponent not QQUickView to load QML. Is correct now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing this:

```
    // Using QQuickView
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Map.qml")));
    QObject *object = component.create();
    QObject *map = object->children().at(1);
```

You're creating a new local instance of you view. So, you don't modify your current view.

The easiest to send data to your view is to use signals/slots. Or, you can pass a pointer on your component to your `MainWindow`:

For example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property int foobar: -1
    Label {
        text: foobar
    }
}
```

```
class Worker: public QObject
{
public:
    Worker(QObject* map): QObject(),
        map(map)
    {
        startTimer(500);
    }

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* ev)
    {
        static int i = 0;
        ++i;
        map->setProperty("foobar", i);
    }
private:
    QObject* map;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    QObject* obj = engine.rootObjects().first();

    Worker* worker = new Worker(obj);

    return app.exec();
}
```

An quick example with signals/slots (useful when the class `Worker` doesn't have to know the inner component):

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    function update(value) {
        label.text = value;
    }

    Label {
        id: label
        text: "None"
    }
}
```

```
class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(): QObject()
    {
        startTimer(500);
    }

    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* ev)
    {
        static int i = 0;
        ++i;
        emit update(i);
    }

signals:
    void update(QVariant newValue);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    QObject* obj = engine.rootObjects().first();

    Worker* worker = new Worker();

    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(update(QVariant)), obj, SLOT(update(QVariant)));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Property in main .qml file is correct like this: property int foobar?

Comment: Yes. I've added the qml content.